# UIActivityController vs 64-bit devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, uiactivityviewcontroller

We recently discovered a problem with our implementaion of UIActivityViewController calling the modal views that present the MailComposerVC, messages, facebook and twiter VCs. On all older devcies the required message composers open and allow the user to compose their message after tappling an icon on the Activity sheet. On 64-bit devices and the 64-bit Simulator when the user taps the relative icon the activity fails (gracefully) and we see the followig error in the console:

```
2013-11-08 12:13:00.885 2life[24880:a0b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xd2795d0  (not loaded)
2013-11-08 12:13:00.891 2life[24880:a0b] Launch Services: Registering unknown app identifier com.apple.mobilemail failed
2013-11-08 12:13:00.892 2life[24880:a0b] Launch Services: Unable to find app identifier com.apple.mobilemail
2013-11-08 12:13:09.267 2life[24880:a0b] _serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"
```

Does anyone have any insight on this?
Here's our method:

```
- (void)showShareView:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text = NSLocalizedString(@"tellAFriendText", @"This is deault text sting for the message.");
    //NSString *text = @"Test";
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tell-a-friend.png"];
    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: text, image, nil];
    UIActivityViewController * activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
   // activityController.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.8f];

    NSArray *exclusions = @[UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypePrint];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = exclusions;
    if (iPhone) {
        [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else if(iPad){
        UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityController];
        popover = pop;
        CGRect rect = [self.menuTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        rect.origin.x = (rect.size.width - rect.size.width/2)/2;
        rect.size.width /= 2;
        rect.size.height /= 2;
        [pop presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.menuTableView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Comment: BTW The important part of the error is that it claims to be looking for the non-existent "Sharing.framework" and that it dumps out with Cocoa error 4097

Comment: Sounds worthy of a [bug report](http://bugreporter.apple.com) to apple

Answer (score 1):

We resolved this recently. Turns out that adjusting the position of the BarButtonTitlePosition with UIAppearnce causes the composer ViewControllers to exit.
Commenting out the following resolves the problem.

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, -2.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];